# Sacar el campo asociado a una clave de un array de diccionarios dentro de un diccionario en phyton

Tags: python, twitter

Me gustaria poder sacar el valor del campo text del siguiente framento de código y nose si tendría que crear una funcion que me recorra el array de diccionarios o lo podria sacar directamente mediante llamadas al objeto que lo contiene. El objeto que lo contiene sería tweet y he llegado a acceder hasta aqui, pero las demas sentencias que pongo me da error de sintaxis. (tweet.entities['hashtags'])

```
    "entities": {
        "hashtags": [{
            "text": "documentation",
            "indices": [211, 225]
        }, {
            "text": "parsingJSON",
            "indices": [226, 238]
        }, {
            "text": "GeoTagged",
            "indices": [239, 249]
        }]
    }
```

He conseguido sacar el valor del primer campo text mediante el siguiente código:

```
        def acceso(hashtags):
            k=''
            for n in hashtags:
                k=n['text']
            return k
```

Pero solo me da el valor del primer text y no consigue sacarme los demas valores de los campos text. Es decir, me devuelve solo 'documentation', pero yo quiero que me devuelva un array con todos los valores del campo text: ['documentation','parsingJSON','GeoTagged']. Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: `return [n["text"] for n in hashtags]` es quizás lo que necesitas?

Comment: Me sigue saliendo solo el primer campo de text :(

Comment: Pues algo no es como nos estás explicando. Acabo de montar un mini ejemplo en replit y funciona. Mira --> https://repl.it/repls/DeliriousThankfulGenres

Comment: La API de la que estoy intentando sacar esos datos es la API de twitter, de la cual yo me he creado un objeto tweet, para de cada tweet de un usuario sacar esas diferentes cosas. El caso es que cada campo texto es un hashtag distinto y con un tweet con distintos hashtag solo me accede al primero. Aqui esta toda la documentacion de la API de twitter: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/data-dictionary/overview/intro-to-tweet-json
Mi objeto tweet es un extended tweet, de manera que directamente desde ese objeto puedo llamar al atributo entities: acceso(tweet.entities["hashtags"])

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurre que para acceder al campo `text` si sabemos que la estructura siempre será la misma podríamos hacer lo siguiente:

```
dicc = {"entities": {
        "hashtags": [{
            "text": "documentation",
            "indices": [211, 225]
        }, {
            "text": "parsingJSON",
            "indices": [226, 238]
        }, {
            "text": "GeoTagged",
            "indices": [239, 249]
        }]
    }
}
```

Partimos de tu diccionario que en este caso lo he llamado `dicc`. Y como sabemos que se trata de un diccionario de diccionarios, llegamos hasta `hashtags` y este ya lo recorremos para poder ver los diferentes valores de `text`.

```
entities = dicc.get('entities')
hashtags = entities.get('hashtags')
for i in hashtags:
  print(i.get('text'))
```

Espero haber entendido bien la duda y que te sirva! Si no, lo comentas y vamos viendo entre todos.

Un saludo.

Comment: Hola buenas! Muchas gracias por la contestación, me dió bastantes ideas y he conseguido sacar el primer elemento del diccionario, pero solo he conseguido sacar el primer elemento asociado a la primera clave. Mi idea es sacar todos los elementos de cada diccionario de la lista, pero no se muy bien como hacerlo. Alguna idea? La función que he hecho es la siguiente:
def acceso(hashtags):
    k=''
    for n in hashtags:
        k=n['text']
    return k

Comment: No termino de entender lo que quieres ¿Sacar también el valor de índices?. Edita tu pregunta, con tus pruebas y un ejemplo claro de lo que necesitas por favor y así  lo entiendo y pienso una respuesta :)